# Is it possible to use non-type template class with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have the following CRTP base class:

```cpp
template <typename T, template <typename> typename CRTPType>
  struct enable_crtp {
    auto underlying() -> T& { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
    auto underlying() const -> const T& {
      return static_cast<const T&>(*this);
    }
  };
```

It works flawless with this type of classes:

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
class BaseA : public enable_crtp<Derived, BaseA> {
public:
  void DoA() {
    this->underlying().DoAImpl();
  }
private:
  friend Derived;
};

class ImplA : public BaseA<ImplA> {
  void DoAImpl() {
    // do something 
  }

  friend BaseA<ImplA>;
};
```

However is there anyway to make it work with non-type template class? Something like this:

```cpp
template<template<size_t> typename Derived>
class BaseB : public enable_crtp<Derived<size_t>, BaseB> {
                                         ^ compile error, template argument for non-type 
                                           template parameter must be an expression
  void DoB() {
    this->underlying().DoBImpl();
  }
}
```

For real problem, i have a `IntegralImageCalculator` which will iterate over image pixels to accumulate sum based on its `i-th order`:

```cpp
  template <size_t Order>
  class IntegralImageCalculator;

  template <>
  class IntegralImageCalculator<1> {
    void Iterate(cv::Mat& input) {
      // Duplicate code
      // ...

      cv::Mat integral_1st_order;
      cv::integral(input, integral_1st_order);

      input.forEach<double>(
        [&integral_1st_order, this](double& pixel, const int* position) {
          Process(integral_1st_order, pixel, position);
        });

      // Duplicate code
      // ...
    }

    void Process(const cv::Mat& integral_1st_order,
                 double& pixel,
                 const int* position) {
      // derived class must implement this
    }
  };

  template <>
  class IntegralImageCalculator<2> {
    void Iterate(cv::Mat& input) {
      // Duplicate code
      // ...

      cv::Mat integral_1st_order;
      cv::Mat integral_2nd_order;
      cv::integral(input, integral_1st_order, integral_2nd_order);

      input.forEach<double>(
        [&integral_1st_order, this](double& pixel, const int* position) {
          Process(integral_1st_order, integral_2nd_order, pixel, position);
        });

      // Duplicate code
      // ...
    }

    void Process(const cv::Mat& integral_1st_order,
                 const cv::Mat& integral_2nd_order,
                 double& pixel,
                 const int* position) {
      // derived class must implement this
    }
  };
```

As you can see, each order has an additional sum matrix. Also, there is a lot of duplicate codes and specific codes for derived classes. I wonder if there is a way to resolve them with CRTP.

Comment: Why do you need `CRTPType` template parameter? In your example it is not used. If you really need it, why not to pass `BaseA<Derived>` instead of `BaseA`?

Comment: On the one hand, your compiler is right; `Derived<size_t>` is not a valid instantiation of your template. On the other hand, have you thought about how you would define `IntegralImageCalculator<1>` with an instantiation of `BaseB` as a base class? How does that `1` get communicated to `enable_crtp`? *(This is one of the times where skipping ahead can be a useful trick -- just don't forget to look back to what you skipped at some point.)*

Comment: @Evg I have updated the code, the trick is to get rid of diamond inheritance, you can see more in here https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/19/crtp-helper/

Comment: I suggest adding the diamond inheritance to your question.

Comment: The fluentcpp link doesn't make any sense. The introductory example [is broken](https://godbolt.org/z/hxcWvWxeb). CRTP doesn't work this way at all. `template <typename T> struct NumericalFunctions : crtp<T>` has nothing to do with CRTP as we know and love. I suggest not paying attention to that page.

Comment: I'm not about tricks, I'm about `CRTPType` being unused in the base class. Do you need it for your particular problem? Make a base CRTP class `template<class T> class Base;` and then derive from it: `template<> class IntegralImageCalculator<1> : public Base<IntegralImageCalculator<1>>;`. From your motivational example I don't see why you need `IntegralImageCalculator` *template* in the base class.

Comment: What do you mean? In your [godbolt urls](https://godbolt.org/z/hxcWvWxeb), obviously it didn't work because your ``NumericalFunctions`` is the base CRTP class. You have no implementation of ``setValue`` and ``getValue``. You should create an Impl class inherit from that one the make it works as ``the CRTP we know and love``

Comment: @Evg My target is to achieve less duplicate code as possible, i just wonder if i can achieve it with CRTP instead of dynamic polymorphism. There is a lot of ``IntegralImageCalculator<N>`` in my code. With your suggestion, I have too manually inherit each of it instances (.e.g ``Integral<1>, Integral<2>, ...``) to ``Base`` and manually again implement duplicate codes.

Comment: You can inherit the primary template: `template<std::size_t N> class IntegralImageCalculator : public Base<IntegralImageCalculator<N>>;`. The actual question here is whether you need `IntegralImageCalculator` template in the base class or just its specialization `IntegralImageCalculator<N>`. CRTP itself is not about template template parameters.

Comment: I copied this line from your page `template <typename T> struct NumericalFunctions : crtp<T>` without change and it's this exact line which is all entirely wrong and broken, no matter what else you add.

Comment: CRTP is supposed to be this way: `template <typename T> struct NumericalFunctions : crtp<NumericalFunctions<T>>` and once you fix it the way it should be, the whole page breaks apart.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Not really. Sometimes you need to introduce an intermediate class(es) into a hierarchy but have the most derived class in CRTP base: `template<class> struct CRTP;`, `template<class D> struct Mid : CRTP<D>;`, `struct A : Mid<A>`. I guess any non-trivial CRTP-based library does this. For example, this pattern can be found in the [Eigen library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html).

Comment: @Evg thanks, I guess you are right, I didn't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Some details are missing from the question, but let me try to give you one possible solution. Even if it is not exactly what you need, I hope it might help you.

```
template<class T>
class Base {
public:
    void Iterate(cv::Mat& input) {
        std::array<cv::Mat, T::Order> integrals;

        std::apply([&input](auto&... integrals) { 
            cv::integral(input, integrals...); }, integrals);

        input.forEach<double>([&integrals, this](double& pixel, const int* position) {
            auto Process = [&](auto&... integrals) {
                static_cast<T*>(this)->Process(integrals..., pixel, position);
            };
            std::apply(Process, integrals);
        });
    }
};

template<std::size_t Order_, class Derived>
class IntegralImageCalculator : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t Order = Order_;
};

class A : public IntegralImageCalculator<1, A> {
public:
    void Process(const cv::Mat&, double& pixel, const int* position) {
        // implementation
    }
};

class B : public IntegralImageCalculator<2, B> {
public:
    void Process(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, double& pixel, const int* position) {
        // implementation
    }
};
```

[Compilable example](https://godbolt.org/z/TM956Wq3d) with trivial stubs for cv.